# Strange behavior : display table + after pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I noticed a strange phenomenon when I apply an `:after` pseudo-element on an element with  `display:table` as you can see here : http://jsfiddle.net/rKzNv/1/

The pseudo-element may behave like a table cell when it should not.

Do you have any idea? Is this a bug?
Thanks!

Comment: Interesting.. it thinks it's a table cell..

Comment: Not necessarily strange...more useful I would have said. It's probably why we can now do 'clearing' with pseudo elements.

Comment: The question itself should contain sufficient code to reproduce the problem and should state what the problem is, instead of just calling it strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN - ::after (:after)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter)

> The CSS :after pseudo-element matches a virtual last child of the selected element.

So `.table:after` matches a virtual *child* of `div.table`, which is allowed to behave as a table cell.

The behaviour changes, when you replace `display: table-cell;` with `display: table-row;`

http://jsfiddle.net/rKzNv/2/

Comment: Interesting! Never knew that. 1+

Comment: Not 'behave as a table-cell' - 'behave as the contents of a table cell', because that's what it is. [Anonymous table objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) are wrapped around the block box, rather than the block box being changed to being a table-cell. To see the difference, see http://jsfiddle.net/rKzNv/3/, noting that vertical-align works with table-cells but not with block boxes.

Comment: @Alohci Thanks a lot for this pointer and for the clarification.

Comment: Thank you to both of you for your explanation! Therefore, it is not possible to add a block element after a table element with the `:after` pseudo-element ? There is no workaround or other solution?

Comment: @tadaa9 You *have* added a block element, but this element was wrapped into a `table-cell`. It depends on what you want to achieve. If you want the "Test 2" appear below the table, you can just replace `table-cell` with `table-row`. As a result, "Test 2" will be wrapped in a virtual `table-row`/`table-cell` child and show up below "Test". See http://jsfiddle.net/rKzNv/2/